# Bluetooth - Output Stream

Tags: android, arduino

I have connected an arduino with my android device and I have set up the connection and obtained Output Stream.

ANDROID PART

```
String one = "1";
byte[] input = one.getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
mConnectedThread.write(input);
```

ARDUINO PART

How can I process the received byte[] and convert it back to String?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a 128byte buffer on the incoming stream. Use

In your loop():

```
char inByte;

// check for bytes in the buffer
if (Serial.available() > 0) {

  // read the available bytes one at a
  // time and purge from buffer
  inByte = Serial.read();

  // print out byte so you can see it on
  // the serial monitor
  Serial.print(inByte);
}
```

If the buffer is big enough for your needs then you won't need to worry about coding anything else. You can deal with the incoming bytes in a char array or read the individual chars into a String object.

There is lots of good information here:
http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/string

...on char arrays and a link at the top of that page to the String object. Let me know if you have further questions, hopefully this gets you at least started and debugging the incoming code correctly